# How to use override WndProc messages to detect usb attach/detach

Tags: c#, usb, serial-port, overriding, wndproc

I'm using this([link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60579/A-USB-Library-to-Detect-USB-Devices)) library to detect attach and detach events of USB devices. After detecting the right device attached(identified with specific VID/PID combination) I open a serial port connection and similarly when the device is detached I close the serial port connection.

My attach event works great and at the end I get a serial port that I can use but I'm having problems inside the detach event. The detach event fires correctly but when code execution reaches `closeCOM(serialPort1)` point it jumps to `wndProc` override loop and prevents execution of  `closeCOM()` and whatever follows.

The library needs `WndProc` messages to detect the events and my code is implemented like this:

```
//Catch Windows messages and pass them to the USBClass class
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    USBPort.ProcessWindowsMessage(ref m);

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Then I have a detach event which executes the following code:

```
 if (!USBClass.GetUSBDevice(VID, PID, ref USBDeviceProperties, false) && USBDeviceConnected)
            {
                //Device is removed
                USBDeviceConnected = false;

                //Close COM port just in case we forgot to disconnect
                closeCOM(serialPort1);

                //update status strip
                strip_device_status.Text = "Disconnected";
            }
```

and here is the `closeCOM` function:

```
    //This function handles COM port closing.
private void closeCOM(SerialPort port)
{
    // If a serial port is open, disconnect it 
    if (port.IsOpen)
    {
        // close the serial port 
        port.Close();
    }
        //update com port status flag
        COMConnected = false;

        //update status strip
        strip_COM_status.Text = "Disconnected";
 }
```

It is `closeCOM()` in particular that's causing this "conflict" because if I comment out that line everything works, except I'm left with an open serial port possibly causing errors later on. What am I doing wrong that's causing the code to jump to `WndProc` override instead of normal execution? I would like to be able to do the port closing in the detach event.

Comment: Running this on a 64-bit operating system?  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.  Or change the platform target to AnyCPU.  The approach is pretty hopeless, you need a time machine that closes the serial port *before* the USB device is detached.

Comment: Yes I'm running on win7 64bit. I did what you suggested and I get a `IOException : The specified port does not exist` for port.Close(). How is that possible since I first check if port.IsOpen ? Regarding your second suggestion, this event will trigger when the external device resets or the connection is lost for whatever reason so I cannot know in advance when it is going to happen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Releasing a unplugged virtual Serial Port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835881/releasing-a-unplugged-virtual-serial-port)

Comment: I think I need to open a new question because it seems the problem is `serialport` related. I check to see if the serialport is not null and it still throws `The specified port does not exist`, this doesn't make sense to me.