# Access To Com Port Is Denied (when detach the port cable)

Tags: .net, serial-port, usb, access-denied

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Releasing a unplugged virtual Serial Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835881/releasing-a-unplugged-virtual-serial-port)

This is my code to connect a serial com port:

```
try{
SRR_serial_port.PortName = comboBox2.Text;
SRR_serial_port.BaudRate = 9600;
SRR_serial_port.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
SRR_serial_port.DataBits = 8;
SRR_serial_port.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
SRR_serial_port.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;       
SRR_serial_port.WriteTimeout = 500;

SRR_serial_port.Open();
}
catch{}
```

and then close the port as follow:

```
SRR_serial_port.Close();
```

now i have a problem in this scenario:

1. open port
2. detach the serial port cable (from computer USB port)
3. attach the cable again
4. close port
5. open port again

this leads to the following error:

> access to the port is denied

In debug mode I see that this error occurs in the following lines of this line:

```
SRR_serial_port.Open();
```

I mean, this line executes and the port state change to open but after a while(during execution of next line) that error appears.

However, this scenario does not produce any error:

1. open port
2. close port
3. detach and reattach cable
4. open port

Comment: but this scenario not produce any error: 1-open port 2-close port 3-detach and reattach cable 4-open port

Comment: Solved: This Problem Exists in .Net 2 , 3 , 3.5 you can use framework 4 (problem does not exist in .net 4)